# Press enter button using Dictation on Mac

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

Is it possible to use macOS dictation to press the enter button (I want to select an item not start a new line)? Is it possible to press the command or function buttons using dictation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ‘press return key’ or ‘enter that’.

[image]

Comment: Does this work for any key such as the command or function keys?

Comment: @Chem No, see the list of commands available from the Accessibility preference pane, under the Dictation section, shown in my screenshot.

Comment: CN you add your own commands?

Comment: @Chem Yes, but not for modifier keys only, so you can make a dictation command which presses ⇧⌘4 for example, but not one which presses ⇧⌘ only. Click the + button to add a command.